# How to get Docker IP in windows Container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-core-1.1, docker-for-windows

I unable to get container IP address to run it from Browser.

**Code Snippet**

```
PS H:\DevAreaLocal\COMPANY - RAD PROJECTS\DockerApp\WebDockerCoreApp> docker-compose build

Building webdockercoreapp
Step 1/5 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
 ---> 4fe9b4d0d093
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /WebDockerCoreApp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b1536c639a21
Step 3/5 : COPY . ./
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 631ca2773407
Step 4/5 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 94a50bb10fbe
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT dotnet WebDockerCoreApp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7003460ebe84
Successfully built 7003460ebe84
Successfully tagged webdockercoreapp:latest

PS H:\DevAreaLocal\COMPANY - RAD PROJECTS\DockerApp\WebDockerCoreApp> docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" 7003460ebe84
```

**Got Bellow ID**

> sha256:7003460ebe84bdc3e8647d7f26f9038936f032de487e70fb4f1ca137f9dde737

**If I run bellow command**

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" 7003460ebe84
```

**Got bellow response**

*Template parsing error: template: :1:19: executing "" at <.NetworkSettings.Net...>: map has no entry for key "NetworkSettings"*

**Docker.Compose.yml file settings**

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  webdockercoreapp:
    image: webdockercoreapp
    build:
      context: ./WebDockerCoreApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5000:80"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

By runnging "`docker network ls`"

got bellow response

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                       DRIVER              SCOPE
f04966f0394c        nat                        nat                 local
3bcb5f906e01        none                       null                local
680d4b4e1a0d        webdockercoreapp_default   nat                 local
```

When I run "`docker network inspect webdockercoreapp_default`"

**Got below response**

```
[
    {
        "Name": "webdockercoreapp_default",
        "Id": "680d4b4e1a0de228329986f217735e5eb35e9925fd04321569f9c9e78508ab88",
        "Created": "2017-12-09T22:59:55.1558081+05:30",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "nat",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "windows",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "0.0.0.0/0",
                    "Gateway": "0.0.0.0"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.windowsshim.hnsid": "ad817a46-e7ff-4fc7-9bb9-d6cf17820b8a"
        },
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "webdockercoreapp"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: add `docker inspect <containerID>` to list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Change in command withing Docker file solve the issue. Bellow is the code snippet

> 1. Since we must build our project, this first container we create is a
>      temporary container which we will use to do just that, and then
>      discard it at the end.
> 2. Next, we copy over the .csproj files into our temporary container's
>      '/app' directory. We do this because .csproj files contain contain a
>      list of package references our project needs. After copying this file,
>      dotnet will read from it and then to go out and fetch all of the
>      dependencies and tools which our project needs.
> 3. Once we've pulled down all of those dependencies, we copy it into the
>      temporary container. We then tell dotnet to publish our application
>      with a release configuration and specify the output path.
> 4. We should have successfully compiled our project. Now we need to build
>      our finalized container.
> 5. Our base image for this final container is similar but different to
>      the FROM command above--it doesn't have the libraries capable of
>      building an ASP.NET app, only running.

**Concussion:**

> We have now successfully performed what is called a multi-stage build.
>   We used the temporary container to build our image and then moved over
>   the published dll into another container so that we minimized the
>   footprint of the end result. We want this container to have the
>   absolute minimum required dependencies to run; if we had kept with
>   using our first image, then it would have come packaged with other
>   layers (for building ASP.NET apps) which were not vital and therefore
>   would increase our image size.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CoreApiDockerSupport.dll"]
```

Put withing `.dockerignore` file

```
bin\
obj\
```

**Note:** Above settings will work if you create a Asp.Net Core Project from Visual Studio IDE with in-build docker support (using `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.ci.build.yml`) files or without it.

[Source 1 - building-sample-app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/building-sample-app)

[Source 2 - asp-net-core-on-linux with Docker](https://stormpath.com/blog/tutorial-deploy-asp-net-core-on-linux-with-docker)

Answer (score 0):

When you're running the command `docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" 7003460ebe84` - you're currently running this against the *image ID* not the *container ID*.

Images are the static asset that you build, and of which containers are run from. So what you need to do is first bring your *image* online, via:

```
docker-compose up
```

Now you'll be able to see the running *containers* via:

```
docker ps
```

Find the container you want; let's say it's `abcd1234`

*Now* you'll be able to run your original command against the *container* - rather than the image.

```
docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" abcd1234
```

This will return the full SHA of the container; and since you originally asked about the network settings; you'll be able to run something like:

```
docker inspect -f "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.your_network_here.IPAddress }}" abcd1234
```

If you're unsure exactly what your network name is (Looks like it should be `nat`) just do a full `docker inspect abcd1234` and look at the output and adjust the filter as needed.

Comment: with 'docker ps' unable to found contaner ID. It is return blank row with header only

Comment: Then you have no containers running, start one first

Comment: I am using Docker for Windows in Windows 10 professional. If no contaner running how I able to build the project using docker command ?

Comment: `docker build -t yourimagename .` will build an image. `docker run yourimagename` can run it